# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve (multiple errors)

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm using the latest versions of React and ReactDOM and despite many efforts and searches, I have not been able to solve this. Anyone run into these issues? Please see attached screenshots. Everything is installed. I have deleted the node_modules dir and package-lock.json multiple times and still no no dice. LMK if any of you needs any other details. Thanks in advance for the help! Time for pizza :)

EDIT: I went into 'react.development.js' and 'react-dom.development.js' and changed the following:

```
var _assign = require('object-assign');
```

TO:

```
var _assign = Object.assign;
```

and it gets rid of the 'object-assign' errors, but obviously I want to avoid this. Also, I compared the 'object-assign' package to the code in the GitHub Repo and found they were wildly different. Did a force install of 'object-assign' and re-compared the code and it matches, but still no dice.

React version: 16.8.6
ReactDom version: 16.8.6

Both specified in 'dependencies'.

@babel/preset-react version: 7.0.0

All Babel versions are the latest as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]